# Access denied for unpublished content in drupal 7

Tags: users

When i unpublished a content in drupal 7, I am getting an access denied message. But for some other unpublished content i am getting page not found message. I need page not found message to all unpublished content. How can i do that? Thanks

Comment: are you login from uid 1 ?

Comment: Are you talking about different content types or the same?

Comment: @ volker yes, different content type.is there any thing to notice when unpublishing an page

Comment: @ monymirza i logged in as super admin. I am not getting what is meant by uid=1. I am using drupal for first time. Kindly explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things to check for to figure out the problem based on your configuration:

1. Are you logged in or logged out while accessing the content?
2. Which user are you logged in with? Is this user the author of this content?
3. Check the permissions of this user (the ones related to unpublished content)...

Let us know if you need help or more details on any of the above.

Cheers.

**UPDATE**: if you want to customize the message that is displayed when access is denied, you can create a new page containing the custom message and then go to "Administration -> Configuration -> System -> Site information -> Default 403 (access denied) page" and set the path to your created page.

Comment: I am getting Access denied when user is not logged in. What i need is user should get Page not found instead of getting Access denied message

Comment: I just updated the answer based on your comment. Please mark as the accepted answer if it solves your problem. Cheers.